# How to insert data to mysql through a modal

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to figure out how to insert data from a modal into a database after hitting submit. The issue I have right now is it just keeps refreshing the page but nothing is being added please help.

here's my modal call:

```
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
            <?php include("new.php");?>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here's my new.php:

```
<?php
 function renderForm($user, $rank, $position, $error)
 {
?>
 <?php 
 if ($error != '')
 {
 echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
 }
 ?> 
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="rank">Rank</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="rank">
 <option value="recruit">recruit</option>
 <option value="officer">officer</option>
 <option value="leader">leader</option>

</select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="position">Position</label>
    <input id="position" class="form-control" type="text" name="position" placeholder="Leader" value="<?php echo $position; ?>" />
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Date">Date</label>
    <input id="Date" class="form-control" type="text" name="date" placeholder="<?php echo date('d M y'); ?>" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Tag">Tag</label>
    <input id="Tag" class="form-control" type="text" name="tag" value="<?php echo $tag; ?>" />
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="AiT">AiT</label>
    <input id="AiT" class="form-control" type="text" name="ait" value="<?php echo $ait; ?>" />
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ServiceStripes">Service Stripes</label>
    <input id="ServiceStripes" class="form-control" type="text" name="ss" value="<?php echo $ss; ?>" />
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Notes">Notes</label>
    <input id="Notes" class="form-control" type="text" name="notes" placeholder="Notes" value="<?php echo $notes; ?>" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php 
}

 include('classes/connect-db.php');

 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 

 $user = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['user']));
 $rank = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['rank']));
 $position = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['position']));
 $date = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['date']));
 $tag = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['tag']));
 $ait = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['ait']));
 $ss = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['ss']));
 $notes = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['notes']));

 if ($user == '' || $rank == '' || $date == '' || $tag == '')
 {
 $error = '<center>ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!</center>';

 @renderForm($user, $rank, $position, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 mysql_query("INSERT players SET user='$user', rank='$rank', position='$position', date='$date', tag='$tag', ait='$ait', ss='$ss', notes='$notes'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 }
 }
 else

 {
 @renderForm('','','');
 }?>
```

This is like the breaking bone of this project. Been working on this for a while now and I'm trying to move away from child windows and into modals but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Would it not be easy to bind (via jQuery) to catch the submit event and just ajax it to a seperate script?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I'm not really good with jquery/ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is because of your conditional statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){...}
```

There is no element named "submit" in your code, which I suspect should be used in conjunction with your submit button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Modify it to:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Having error reporting on, would have signaled an "Undefined index" notice.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Footnotes:

Consider moving over to a safer MySQL API:

Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: Plus 1, you're the winner Fred!

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have another issue. Now after the info is submitted the form closes but when I opens it doesn't show the form. Also, everytime I refresh page it enters form info again doubling it in the database.

Comment: Try using a header to redirect upon successful query. @Riley

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have another issue regarding another part of my form. This too is trying to get something in a modal. I also have an issue where I can't have 2 differen't modals on the same page or they won't open. Can I open up another question and you help me with it or is there another way I could contact you.

Comment: @Riley Try opening a new question, because TBH I may not be able to be able to help. Otherwise, I would have helped you without having to open a new question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559872/how-to-edit-data-in-mysql-through-a-modal